# Mitsubishi PLC - The parameter Set Value is Out of Range - GX Works3

Tags: plc, structured-text

We have a PLC application that has been created in GXWorks3.

We're using an IQ-F FX5U-32MR/DS with two analogue components:

[image: PLC Setup]

We're able to run our very simple program on the simulator and are having no issues, however when writing the changes to the PLC, we get the following error:

[image: Error message]

We can't find where this parameter lives, and where to set it. According to the manuals, we think these means the set value is out of range, but we're not sure where the range is defined.

**What could be wrong with this parameter, and how do we change it?**

Comment: Have you tried contacting the Mitsubishi support? This sounds a problem that they should help with. Of course, provide the answer also here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the firmware on the FX5. The FX5-8AD we have attached requires version 1.5+.